# how to merge tablecolom in TableLayout

Tags: android-layout

i want to create using TableLayout and its generating problem like shown in below image-1 but i want to TableLayout like image-2.[image]
i give my XML Code which i create.!

Image-1 , but i want to another Perfect output like next image 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use nested Layout like i given below.

First : LinearLayout

```
        take TextView in LinearLayout
```

Second : Take TableLayout in LinearLayout

set android:layout_length and android.layout_width as fill_parent.

```
           in table layout , take two TextView and EditText and Button.
```

i hope it can work as you want.